# Vaadin unbuffered grids won't close

Tags: java, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

I am having a weird problem on my Vaadin app. I have a screen with two separate unbuffered grids.
The user is able to edit the data in those two grids and then click a "Save" button to save the changes made.
My problem is that I want to close the editors when the user clicks on "Save".
I tried the following code:

```
private void closeEditors() {
    if (tab1.getEditor().isOpen()) {
        tab1.getEditor().closeEditor();
    }
    if (tab2.getEditor().isOpen()) {
        tab2.getEditor().closeEditor();
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this code doesn't work, editors stay opened. I also tried calling the `cancel` method but in vain.
I am using Vaadin 14.
I am posting this here with not much hope of finding an answer, this problem seems really precise.
But with any luck, maybe someone has experienced a similar issue ?
Maybe there is another glitchier way of forcing my editors to close ?

Any suggestion would be of great help, thanks in advance for anything you could think of !

**EDIT: a little more code**

This is the grids:

```
private Grid<Map<String, String>> tab1;
private Grid<Map<String, List<String>>> tab2;
```

This is the save function

```
public void saveData() {
    saveDataFromTab1();
    saveDataFromTab2();

    try {
        ServicesProxyImpl.getInstance().updateInBD(someObject);
        saveButton.setEnabled(false);
        cancelButton.setEnabled(false);
        closeEditors();

        Dialog dialog = VaadinComponentUtils.generateDialog(Constantes.MSG_SAVE_OK);
        dialog.open();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Dialog dialog = VaadinComponentUtils.generateDialog(Constantes.MSG_SAVE_KO);
        dialog.open();
    }
}
```

And this is the save button:

```
public Button getSaveButton() {
    Button saveButton= VaadinComponentUtils.generateButton("Save",
            VaadinIcon.CHECK_CIRCLE_O, null, true);
    saveButton.setEnabled(false);
    saveButton.addClickListener(event -> saveData());

    return saveButton;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
I have noticed something, when I click on an element of one of my two grids, I want the editor to open for that specific element and I want to close the editor on the other grid (the one not concerned by the modification).
 This works ! My grids behave like I want. 
It seems I am only losing control over my editors after I have actually modified one of the cells and clicked on my save button.
The `isOpen` function returns false on both grids after I call my `closeEditors` function, so it seems the grid thinks its editor is closed but it is still opened on my UI.

**EDIT 3: I have found a workaround**
Well, I have solved my problem by adding a close event listener on both my grids and calling `resetGrids` when the close event is fired. This function simply removes the grids from the UI, fetches the data to be displayed and then adds the grid one again, both editors being closed. 
I guess it solves my problem but I would have wanted to understand what was going on...

```
    private void closeEditors() {
        tableauHoraires.getEditor().addCloseListener(e -> resetGrids());
        tableauRamassagePorteAPorte.getEditor().addCloseListener(e -> resetGrids());
        if (tableauRamassagePorteAPorte.getEditor().isOpen()) {
            tableauRamassagePorteAPorte.getEditor().closeEditor();
        }
        if (tableauHoraires.getEditor().isOpen()) {
            tableauHoraires.getEditor().closeEditor();
            tableauHoraires.getEditor().refresh();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you modify your example to show where you are invoking your `closeEditors()` method?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added some code. Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the objects in your grid have proper equals and hashcode methods and that the field(s) being edited do not influence them.

I use the PK from the database.

Comment: Absolutely, being unaware of the way Vaadin uses equals / hashCode can cause really weird behavior. The official documentation can be found here: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/binding-data/data-provider#data-binding.data-provider.item-identifiers

Answer (score 0):

The `Grid` editor needs to know what has changed in order to close the right thing.
But you changed your object's data, so most likely, the item cannot be longer found (like `int indexOf(object)`).
Please make use that the Object has a never changing `ID` field, and that `hashCode` and `equals` just uses that `ID`.

Example:

you have a list of `Person(firstName, lastName)`.
Now copy a item from the list, change the first name of the copied items.
If you now try to find the index of the copied item in the list, you will not get any.

Now change the implementation of `Person(id, firstname, lastName)` and let `id` be a `private final String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()`.
Change the `int hashCode()` and `boolean equals(Object o)` to only use the `id` field.
Now copy a item from the list, change the first name of the copied items.
If you now try to find the index of the copied item in the list, you will find it again, because the id did not change.